# Python OPC UA Client Security Policy (basic 256sha256)?

Tags: python, encryption, protocols, client-certificates, opc-ua

I have implemented an OPC UA Client in Python by accessing Anonymously to the OPC UA Server, But now when it comes to the encryption I founded out that Python OPC UA Package don't support/allow Basic 256sha256 in which OPC Foundation finds the others Obsolete or no longer considered secure.
https://opcfoundation.org/UA/SecurityPolicy/#Basic256

http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkhp/1.0.0/html/_l2_ua_discovery_connect.html

I am using this packages:

```
from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua
```

in which the connection doesn't allow its security policy...

```
client.set_security_string("Basic256Sha256,SignAndEncrypt,certificate-example.der,private-key-example.pem")
```

Does anyone knows any other way to implementwith PYTHON an OPC UA Client with Basic256Sha256 Security Policy since on the links before it says that the others are no longer considered secure (Basic128Rsa15) or used.

Comment: This question is outdated. [python-opcua](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/) has in the meantime started supporting application certificates with Basic256Sha256. However, user authentication certificates with SHA-256 signatures are not automagically supported but need [a little tweak](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio/issues/137).

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of freeopcua module has added support to latest security protocols and certificates. Please do try the same code with latest modules and share the results for more info on the same!

Thanks.